# How to append a string variable in middle of another string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two variables as below and want to add the second variable 'b' after 2nd div in variable 'a'.

```
var a = `<form action='javascript:void(0)' class='nani_chat_form'>
            <div class='nani_chat_name'><input placeholder='Name' type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_email'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Email' type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_phne'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Mobile'type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_sub' style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
            </form>`

var b = `<div class='nani_chat_city'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='pincode' type='text'></div>`
```

Expected output -

```
var c = `<form action='javascript:void(0)' class='nani_chat_form'>
            <div class='nani_chat_name'><input placeholder='Name' type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_email'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Email' type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_city'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='pincode' type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_phne'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Mobile'type='text'></div>
            <div class='nani_chat_sub' style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
            </form>`
```

Comment: Define `b` first, then define `a` as `\`<form>...${b}...</form>\``: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) -- Since you tagged this with jQuery, you can also do: `var $c = $(a).append(b, ".nani_chat_email")`

Comment: Scratch that jQuery suggestion; I misread the manual entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`jQuery.parseHTML()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to *parse a string into an array of DOM nodes* and use [**`.after()`**](https://api.jquery.com/after/) on that to *insert the element after the matched element.*

You can return back the DOM nodes in the form of string by using `.prop('outerHTML')`:

**Demo:**

```js
var a = `<form action='javascript:void(0)' class='nani_chat_form'>
<div class='nani_chat_name'><input placeholder='Name' type='text'></div>
<div class='nani_chat_email'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Email' type='text'></div>
<div class='nani_chat_phne'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='Mobile'type='text'></div>
<div class='nani_chat_sub' style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
</form>`;

var b = `<div class='nani_chat_city'><span class='error'></span><input placeholder='pincode' type='text'></div>`

var c = $.parseHTML(a);
$(c).find('.nani_chat_email').after(b);
$('body').append(c); // append to test
console.log($(c).prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```